# Change back Button Title after Push Segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I Have a DetailViewController that is pushed from MasterViewController as in figure below:

[image]

When the detail view shows up it has a "back" button title is equal to the file name of the MasterViewController: "Master" (because I have a custom title with two labels in MasterViewController).

Is there a way to modify it?

[image]

MasterViewController compound title:

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, sum + 20)];

[titleView addSubview:first];
[titleView addSubview:second];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = titleView;
```

I have tried with no luck:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"AAA";
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"AAA";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"AAA";
```

I have noticed that in the view hierarchy there is no `NavigationItem` or `NavigationBar` in DetailViewController, and thus adding it there is no possibility to add the left arrow to the `BarButtonItem`

[image]

There is also another question similar to this but with no clear answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is showing is the title property of the view controller so in MasterViewController set

```
self.title = @"AAA"
```

Comment: What do you mean with "custom title" and "takes the file name"? The back button takes the title that is set in the view controller the back button refers to normally. I don't see anything that you have done to change that behaviour...

Comment: The "compound" title has nothing to do with the title property of the view controller. Can you show What you have set self.title to in MasterViewController?